# How would I parse a shell string in JS?

Tags: javascript, shell, xtermjs

So I'm creating a terminal environment using XTerm.js, and I want to parse shell commands like so:

```bash
echo hi >> cool.txt && neofetch
```

would become

```js
[
  { command: 'echo', args: ['hi'], operators: [{ operator: '>>', to: 'cool.txt' }] },
  { command: 'neofetch' }
]
```

I would like to have all the bash operators preferably.

I've so far tried using npm libraries such as shell-quote, however they do not satisfy my needs.

Comment: That's not trivial.  Are you going to handle `>`, `<`, `|`, `||`, `2>`, `2>&`, and so on?  Remember that `&&` doesn't mean "and then do this".  It means "and then do this IF the last command succeeded".  Are you specifically targeting bash?

Comment: `shell-quote` is exactly what you need.  It will do the parsing and handle any ridiculous quoting.  It is then YOUR job to supply the actions for the parsing it did.  That's your task.  It should be fun, actually.

Comment: Why don't you think `shell-quote/parse` does what you need?